# O nome "Json" não exite no contexto atual

Tags: c#, json, api, newtonsoft

Boa tarde, tenho a seguinte parte da minha classe que serviria para alimentar os objetos obtidos através de um json online.

```
public JsonResult GetJson()
    {
        string res;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        // Download string
        string value = client.DownloadString(http://localhost/info.json);

        // Write values
        res = value;
        dynamic dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);
        var lstInstagramObjects = new List<GitHubModel>();

        foreach (var obj in dyn.data)
        {
            lstInstagramObjects.Add(new GitHubModel()
            {
                Players_Total = int.Parse(obj.players_total.ToString()),
                Players_Online = int.Parse(obj.players_online.ToString()),
            });
        }

        return Json(lstInstagramObjects, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public class GitHubModel
    {
        public List<GitHubObjects> data { get; set; }
        public dynamic ApiTunel { get; internal set; }
        public dynamic Players_Total { get; internal set; }
        public dynamic Players_Online { get; internal set; }
    }
    public class GitHubObjects
    {
        public string api_tunel { get; set; }
        public string nome_server { get; set; }
        public string nome_launcher { get; set; }
        public int server_status { get; set; }
        public int players_online { get; set; }
        public int players_total { get; set; }
        public string discord { get; set; }
        public string teamspeak { get; set; }
        public string server_ip { get; set; }
        public int server_port { get; set; }
        public int version { get; set; }
        public string update_link_zip { get; set; }
        public string tokovoip_link { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Porem recebo o seguinte erro no visual sutdio quando tento efetuar a compilação:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Rodei o Stack e quebrei a cabeça pensando o que poderia ser, mas sem sucesso, PS: não tenho experiencia com C# e estou tentando dar uma familiarizada com a linguagem.

Comment: Isso é ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Estou montando em C#

Comment: C# é a linguagem. Ao que parece você está usando um framework web (como ASP.NET ou ASP.NET Core) e, provavelmente, é deste framework que vem o tal `JsonResult` ou o método `Json` que você está tentando usar. Você precisa saber se está usando ASP.NET e qual a versão está usando, sem isso é impossível te ajudar.

Comment: Desculpa a falta de informações é que realmente estou caindo de paraquedas para tentar aprender o C# mesmo, quando criei o projeto o que me recordo era um projeto no visual que estava como .NET FrameWork, como posso saber qual ASP.NET estou utilizando? Só encontrei .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: @BrendownF no Visual Studio,  vá em "Solution Explorer", clique com o botão direito do mouse no projeto desejado, clique em "Properties" e veja a informação na aba "Application" (não lembro dos itens de menu em português)

Answer (score 0):

Para quem estiver com problemas igual o meu, a solução depois de revirar a internet para mim foi, definir a classe onde estava minha função como um controller, eu havia me esquecido de definir ela.

```
public class Json: Controller
{
}
```